# Rounded corners of -webkit-tap-highlight-color area

Tags: html, css, webkit, touch

I assume that default (non-transparent) `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is the fastest way to react to the user's touch before doing complex DOM manipulations. This is especially noticeable on older, slower devices.

As far as I understand, the `border-radius` rule is not applicable to tap-highlighting. Is there still some way to do this for elements like rounded buttons?

```css
button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
button:active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Enter</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make a wrapper around the button and make it `overflow: hidden`, and apply rounded corners to that wrapper

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: 2em;
}

button {
    border: none;
    padding: 1em 2em;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <button>Test</button>
</span>
```